# Why can't I Seq.take more than 5 values?

Tags: f#

Whilst trying to understand Seq.unfold, I have been playing with the following F# that produces a sequence of the triangle numbers...

```
let tri_seq = 
  1.0 
  |> Seq.unfold (fun x -> Some (0.5 * x * (x + 1.0), x + 1.0)) 
  |> Seq.map (fun n -> int n)
```

This seems to work fine, in that I can do the following...

```
tri_seq |> Seq.nth 10
```

...and it shows the right number, whatever value I pass to it.

Now, I'm trying to print out the first (say) ten values in the sequence, rather that the above code which only gets the nth. I tried the following...

```
tri_seq |> Seq.take 10 |> Seq.map (fun n -> printfn "%d" n)
```

...but that only prints the first five values. Whatever I use for the value passed to Seq.take, I only ever get a maximum of five results, even though when using Seq.nth, I can go as far as I like.

Anyone able to explain this to me? Why can't I get past the fifth value?

Comment: @Luaan Sorry, I broke the code to avoid horizontal scrolling. Seems I did it wrong! I've put it on one line now

Comment: Don't forget that in F#, indentation isn't just whitespace. I fixed the problem for you, hope you don't mind :)

Comment: @Luaan I knew it was significant, I just haven't got it completely clear yet! Thanks for fixing the code, apart form making it more readable, it was instructive for me to see how it could be broken

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `Seq.map` to print the values. Sequences are lazy and the resulting sequence is never evaluated - you see 5 values probably because F# Interactive prints the first five elements of the sequence.

You can use `Seq.iter` which iterates over the whole sequence:

```
tri_seq |> Seq.take 10 |> Seq.iter (fun n -> printfn "%d" n)
```

The key difference is that `Seq.map` returns a new sequence with the values produced by the function you specify while `Seq.iter` does not return anything and just iterates over the input.

In this case, you can actually use partial function application and make the code a bit shorter:

```
tri_seq |> Seq.take 10 |> Seq.iter (printfn "%d")
```

Comment: Ah, so is Seq.map like the C# IEnumerable, in that it generates something that you can enumerate, but isn't actually enumerated yet? I'm still quite new at F#, so still learning this kind of stuff!

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel `Seq` is actually an alias for `IEnumerable` :) `Seq.map` corresponds to `Enumerable.Select`.